# Show a key of item in firebase database

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a firebase-database like this:

[image]

```
       User:

           84e2UDSLjeQPqBMjhX3oNbz7Qni2:

                anno: "1991"
                citta:"Rome"
                cognome:"FOXX"
                nome: "JAMIE"
```

How I can print the key of one user stored in database?
I'm using JavaScript, I'm trying this:

```
var userDB = firebase.database().ref("User");
userDB.once("value").then(function(snapshot) {
snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {

key = childSnapshot.val().key;
window.alert(key);

});
});
```

But is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
key = childSnapshot.val().key;
```

into this:

```
key = childSnapshot.key;
```

> [key](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot#key)
>
> The key (last part of the path) of the location of this DataSnapshot.

The `key` is a property to access it you need to use the following `objectName.property`